# How to display single items from array using JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Its my first Question here, so be kind ^^ Im training myself some JS/Jquery/Ajax.
Short: Projekt to filter closest location of a specific company to our current postal zip.
So, here is my "work" so far: On index.php im using a simple form like this:

```
<form id="ajaxForm">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="plzInput" name="plzInput" placeholder="99999"
                       aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required>
                <button type="submit" id="plzSubmit" name="plzSubmit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
            </form>
```

Im passing some data to ajax.php using ajax:

```
 var request;
     $("#ajaxForm").submit(function (event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         if (request) {
             request.abort();
         }
         var $form = $(this);

         //Caching
         var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

         var serializedData = $form.serialize();
         $inputs.prop("disabled", true);
         request = $.ajax({
             url: "ajax.php",
             type: "post",
             data: serializedData
         });
         request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
             console.log("in ajax.php geschrieben!");
             console.log(response);
             showResults(response);


         });
         request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             console.error(
                 "The following error occurred: " +
                 textStatus, errorThrown
             );
         });
         request.always(function () {
             $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
         });
     });

     function showResults(data){
         alert(data);

     }
 });
```

Here the data finally getting handled using php (db queries, calculations, result). Now im struggling on how to send my resuslts from ajax.php back to index. All in all, i want to send back an array from SQLquery, and show those values into existing html inputs using js/jquery on index.php. But i don't know why the response of ajax.php isnt readable by the JS/Jquery. I think there is something wrong with php arrays vs js arrays. Is there a way to send "multiple" responses or even an array of responses?

im glad for every help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to do this is by using JSON.

On the PHP side, in `ajax.php`, you use [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode) to encode your array as a string.

That JSON string is then received in your Javascript AJAX as the `response`. There you can turn it back into an array with [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
let array = JSON.parse(response);
```

JQuery also has a shorthand for this, see:

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Thx, I already tried it before. Just tried it again, but it still doenst work. I encoded it - result like: "{"id":4,"name":"A\u00dcG Personall\u00f6sungen","street":"Detmolder Str."...}". On index.php i tried to JSON.parse the array, and tried to alert, where it says: [onject Object]. Some Tipps left?

Comment: EDIT: Got it shown with "alert(JSON.stringify(exampleObject, null, 4));". Now i only need to know how to reach those values ^^

Comment: @JonasOldenkott If your `alert(array)` says `[object Object]` that means you did it. Just the way you provide yourself with feedback is not the best. It's better to use `console.log(array)` and check the console. There you will actually see the array without using `JSON.stringify()`. See: [How to Print to the Console in JS](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-console-log-example-how-to-print-to-the-console-in-js/).

Comment: Aight, got it. Usually im logging and console and check with alert for current debugs, but nvm. Can u tell me how to access e.g. the id now? Parsed response is this:
"{"id":4,"name":"A\u00dcG Personall\u00f6sungen","street":"Detmolder Str.","number":"57","zip":33100,"place":"Paderborn","category":"Medizin","lat":51.72969,"lon":8.76302}"

Comment: @JonasOldenkott Yes, actually, it is not an array, it's a object. In JSON `{....}` signified an object and `[....]` an array. In Javascript you can get the id by using `let id = array.id;`. I kept the `array` name for clarity. Similar you can get at the zip code by using `let zipCode = array.zip;`.

Comment: @JonasOldenkott Glad I could help. For the purists JQuery isn't really Javascript, they write everything in "pure" Javascript. Doing the same without loading an extra resource is their idea of fun. However, I like JQuery, I find its syntax just a bit more elegant.

Comment: Ah okay, but its still so hard for me to decide if JS or JQuery is right in front of me :D